# Laravel loop issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need help with looping my product options, this is what i have now:

[image: shoot]

What I want is simply get 2 row's only one for `color` and another for `size` and in dropdown in front of each one have all items.

here is my blade code:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($product->suboptions as $option)
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $option->option->title }}</td>
    <td class="text-left">
       <select name="" id="">
         <option value="{{$option->id}}">{{$option->title}} - {{ number_format($option->price, 0) }}</option>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

## UPDATE

my dd result of `{dd($product->suboptions)}}`

[image: shoot2]

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried `print_r($products->suboptions)`? Do color and size appear multiple times?

Comment: @BaileyParker what do you mean what i have done? i shared my code in question. here is my controller code `$product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: I mean SO isn't here to debug your code for you. You are expected to show to effort in debugging. In this case, I'd recommend `print_r($product->suboptions)` before the blade loop, so you can see if the suboptions are indeed duplicated.

Comment: @BaileyParker I shared `dd` result

Comment: in this line {{ $option->option->title }} where is option method refer to(what table)?

Comment: @SalarBahador `option` in parent of `suboptions` in foreach. like `category`, `sub-category`

Comment: @mafortis cant you get options in controller and refer to suboptions instead? or it must be this way? you want to access sub option through product, right?

Comment: @SalarBahador yes, but the thing is that my products are related to suboptions and not options directly. that means i have `suboption_id` column in my products table and not `option_id` that's why i cannot access through options otherwise my problem would be solved with 2 foreach only.

Comment: You'll probably need to add a group by clause on your query

Comment: @btl please help if you know the way.

Comment: Try something like: `Product::with(['product.suboptions' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('color');
    }])->get();`

Comment: @btl that way 1- i cannot get my option title (my suboptions parent) 2- will load all suboptions even if not included product i'm visiting.

Comment: @btl `$opts = $product->with(['suboptions' => function($query){
      $query->groupBy('suboption_id');
    }])->get();`

Comment: You can eager load more than 1 relation. Add product.suboption.option and then restrict the suboptions using a having or wherehas clause.

Comment: @btl no this is not the way i'm looking for! or at least i can't get it to work :/

Comment: Grouping is exactly what you need if your desired outcome is 2 rows, 1 for color and 1 for size. Start with my first example and then add wherehas clauses or further subqueries. Or manually loop the color first and create an array with the structure you need, but that's not optimized as sql can handle this for you. You can also add $with properties to your models to always include relations in queries, but be careful of performance impacts doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group them together with the mapToGroups() function for a collection
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-maptogroups

```
$something = $product->suboptions->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item->option->title => $item];
});
```

You should dd() that to see what the output is and understand it.
After that you can just cycle through them with foreach, your blade should be something like

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($something as $optiontitle => $optioncollection)
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $optiontitle }}</td>
    <td class="text-left">
      <select name="" id="">
        @foreach($optioncollection as $suboption)
          <option value="{{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: hallelujah :))), works just fine as i wanted, thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing how if i need to put comma in between except using dropdown? `implode` them?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the best I guess.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-implode Just try $optioncollection->implode('id', ','); or whatever field you wanna implode over and with what syntax inbetween, if you wanna have titles, you could do $optioncollection->implode('title', '  -  ') for example. In general I would suggest trying https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods a little bit :)

Answer (score 1):

For accomplishing that you need to get option first, and write a method to access options via products id or products object. so you can right something like this in products model:

```
   public function get_option($product_id){

       $sub_options = Product::whereId($product_id)->first()->suboptions()->get();

       $option = array();
       foreach($sub_options as $sub_option){
         $option[] = $sub_option->options()->get();
       }

    return $option;
  }
```

And then in view, you just call this method and put it in 2 foreach, one for option and the other for sub-option. like this code below:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($product->get_option($product->id) as $key=>$value)
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $value->title }}</td>
     <td class="text-left">
       <select name="" id="">
         @foreach($value->suboptions() as $key=>$value2)
         <option value="{{$value2->id}}">{{$value2->title}} - {{number_format($value2->price, 0) }}</option>
         @endforeach
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I don't know whats your model methods but you can get the concept.

**I Repeat again**
you should not copy my code exactly. just follow along with the concept of what am I saying.

But this time according to your eloquent methods. this code should work.

Comment: Undefined variable: product_id

Comment: `public function options(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
  }` , 
  `public function suboptions(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Suboption::class, 'product_suboption', 'product_id', 'suboption_id');
  }`

Comment: @mafortis It is a concept. I mean your product Id. wait i will edit it.

Comment: @mafortis you should add belong to relations with exactly same method names in product model. this way first you access the sub option. after that the option that related to that product.

Comment: i get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::suboption() `

Comment: @mafortis I edited my answer. if any problem showed again. let me know.

Comment: this time for options `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::options()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163450/discussion-between-salar-bahador-and-mafortis).

Comment: I recommend to use Relations